# My site with ReCaptcha is pulling google.com/js/th/something.js. Am I being hacked?

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I noticed that one of my submission pages with ReCaptcha is pulling this file:

```
http://www.google.com/js/th/tCBzJRqneV5tJFCAUdKmLPYTyVH8SN5m5IZzuhnsVzY.js
```

Of course, being hosted at Google, I want to assume this must be fine. Although the file contents start with this:

```
/* Anti-spam. Questions? Write to (rot13) guvagvary-dhrfgvbaf@tbbtyr.pbz */
```

...followed by a very long `eval()` statement. This is the beginning of it (edit: this is now the entire code block):

```
(function(){eval('var f=function(a,b,c){if(b=typeof a,"object"==b)if(a){if(a instanceof Array)return"array";if(a instanceof Object)return b;if(c=Object.prototype.toString.call(a),"[object Window]"==c)return"object";if("[object Array]"==c||"number"==typeof a.length&&"undefined"!=typeof a.splice&&"undefined"!=typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable&&!a.propertyIsEnumerable("splice"))return"array";if("[object Function]"==c||"undefined"!=typeof a.call&&"undefined"!=typeof a.propertyIsEnumerable&&!a.propertyIsEnumerable("call"))return"function"}else return"null";else if("function"==b&&"undefined"==typeof a.call)return"object";return b},n=function(a,b,c,d,e){c=a.split("."),d=g,c[0]in d||!d.execScript||d.execScript("var "+c[0]);for(;c.length&&(e=c.shift());)c.length||b===k?d=d[e]?d[e]:d[e]={}:d[e]=b},p=Date.now||function(){return+new Date},r=/&/g,t=/</g,u=/>/g,w=/"/g,x=/\'/g,k=void 0,g=this,z,A="".oa?"".ma():"",E=(/[&<>"\']/.test(A)&&(-1!=A.indexOf("&")&&(A=A.replace(r,"&amp;")),-1!=A.indexOf("<")&&(A=A.replace(t,"&lt;")),-1!=A.indexOf(">")&&(A=A.replace(u,"&gt;")),-1!=A.indexOf(\'"\')&&(A=A.replace(w,"&quot;")),-1!=A.indexOf("\'")&&(A=A.replace(x,"&#39;"))),new function(){p()},function(a,b,c,d,e,h){try{if(this.j=2048,this.c=[],B(this,this.b,0),B(this,this.l,0),B(this,this.p,0),B(this,this.h,[]),B(this,this.d,[]),B(this,this.H,"object"==typeof window?window:g),B(this,this.I,this),B(this,this.r,0),B(this,this.F,0),B(this,this.G,0),B(this,this.f,C(4)),B(this,this.o,[]),B(this,this.k,{}),this.q=true,a&&","==a[0])this.m=a;else{if(window.atob){for(c=window.atob(a),a=[],e=d=0;e<c.length;e++){for(h=c.charCodeAt(e);255<h;)a[d++]=h&255,h>>=8;a[d++]=h}b=a}else b=null;(this.e=b)&&this.e.length?(this.K=[],this.s()):this.g(this.U)}}catch(l){D(this,l)}}),G=(E.prototype.g=function(a,b,c,d){d=this.a(this.l),a=[a,d>>8&255,d&255],c!=k&&a.push(c),0==this.a(this.h).length&&(this.c[this.h]=k,B(this,this.h,a)),c="",b&&(b.message&&(c+=b.message),b.stack&&(c+=":"+b.stack)),3<this.j&&(c=c.slice(0,this.j-3),this.j-=c.length+3,c=F(c),G(this,this.f,H(c.length,2).concat(c),this.$))},function(a,b,c,d,e,h){for(e=a.a(b),b=b==a.f?function(b,c,d,h){if(c=e.length,d=c-4>>3,e.ba!=d){e.ba=d,d=(d<<3)-4,h=[0,0,0,a.a(a.G)];try{e.aa=I(J(e,d),J(e,d+4),h)}catch(s){throw s;}}e.push(e.aa[c&7]^b)}:function(a){e.push(a)},d&&b(d&255),d=c.length,h=0;h<d;h++)b(c[h])}),K=function(a,b,c,d,e,h,l,q,m){return c=function(a,s,v){for(a=d[e.D],s=a===b,a=a&&a[e.D],v=0;a&&a!=h&&a!=l&&a!=q&&a!=m&&20>v;)v++,a=a[e.D];return c[e.ga+s+!(!a+(v>>2))]},d=function(){return c()},e=E.prototype,h=e.s,l=e.Q,m=e.g,q=E,d[e.J]=e,c[e.fa]=a,a=k,d},L=function(a,b,c){if(b=a.a(a.b),!(b in a.e))throw a.g(a.Y),a.u;return a.t==k&&(a.t=J(a.e,b-4),a.B=k),a.B!=b>>3&&(a.B=b>>3,c=[0,0,0,a.a(a.p)],a.Z=I(a.t,a.B,c)),B(a,a.b,b+1),a.e[b]^a.Z[b%8]},F=function(a,b,c,d,e){for(a=a.replace(/\\r\\n/g,"\\n"),b=[],d=c=0;d<a.length;d++)e=a.charCodeAt(d),128>e?b[c++]=e:(2048>e?b[c++]=e>>6|192:(b[c++]=e>>12|224,b[c++]=e>>6&63|128),b[c++]=e&63|128);return b},B=function(a,b,c){if(b==a.b||b==a.l)a.c[b]?a.c[b].V(c):a.c[b]=M(c);else if(b!=a.d&&b!=a.f&&b!=a.h||!a.c[b])a.c[b]=K(c,a.a);b==a.p&&(a.t=k,B(a,a.b,a.a(a.b)+4))},I=function(a,b,c,d){try{for(d=0;76138654016!=d;)a+=(b<<4^b>>>5)+b^d+c[d&3],d+=2379332938,b+=(a<<4^a>>>5)+a^d+c[d>>>11&3];return[a>>>24,a>>16&255,a>>8&255,a&255,b>>>24,b>>16&255,b>>8&255,b&255]}catch(e){throw e;}},N=function(a,b){return b<=a.ca?b==a.h||b==a.d||b==a.f||b==a.o?a.n:b==a.P||b==a.H||b==a.I||b==a.k?a.v:b==a.w?a.i:4:[1,2,4,a.n,a.v,a.i][b%a.da]},O=(E.prototype.la=function(a,b){b.push(a[0]<<24|a[1]<<16|a[2]<<8|a[3]),b.push(a[4]<<24|a[5]<<16|a[6]<<8|a[7]),b.push(a[8]<<24|a[9]<<16|a[10]<<8|a[11])},function(a,b,c,d){for(b={},b.N=a.a(L(a)),b.O=L(a),c=L(a)-1,d=L(a),b.self=a.a(d),b.C=[];c--;)d=L(a),b.C.push(a.a(d));return b}),Q=(E.prototype.ja=function(a,b,c,d){if(3==a.length){for(c=0;3>c;c++)b[c]+=a[c];for(d=[13,8,13,12,16,5,3,10,15],c=0;9>c;c++)b[3](b,c%3,d[c])}},function(a,b,c,d){return c=a.a(a.b),a.e&&c<a.e.length?(B(a,a.b,a.e.length),P(a,b)):B(a,a.b,b),d=a.s(),B(a,a.b,c),d}),H=(E.prototype.ka=function(a,b,c,d){d=a[(b+2)%3],a[b]=a[b]-a[(b+1)%3]-d^(1==b?d<<c:d>>>c)},function(a,b,c,d){for(d=b-1,c=[];0<=d;d--)c[b-1-d]=a>>8*d&255;return c}),M=function(a,b,c){return b=function(){return c()},b.V=function(b){a=b},c=function(){return a},b},R=function(a,b,c,d){return function(){if(!d||a.q)return B(a,a.P,arguments),B(a,a.k,c),Q(a,b)}},P=(E.prototype.a=function(a,b){if(b=this.c[a],b===k)throw this.g(this.ea,0,a),this.u;return b()},function(a,b){a.K.push(a.c.slice()),a.c[a.b]=k,B(a,a.b,b)}),J=function(a,b){return a[b]<<24|a[b+1]<<16|a[b+2]<<8|a[b+3]},C=function(a,b){for(b=Array(a);a--;)b[a]=255*Math.random()|0;return b},D=function(a,b){a.m=("E:"+b.message+":"+b.stack).slice(0,2048)};z=E.prototype,z.M=[function(){},function(a,b,c,d,e){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=a.a(b),b=N(a,b),e=N(a,c),e==a.i||e==a.n?d=""+d:0<b&&(1==b?d&=255:2==b?d&=65535:4==b&&(d&=4294967295)),B(a,c,d)},function(a,b,c,d,e,h,l,q,m){if(b=L(a),c=N(a,b),0<c){for(d=0;c--;)d=d<<8|L(a);B(a,b,d)}else if(c!=a.v){if(d=L(a)<<8|L(a),c==a.i)if(c="",a.c[a.w]!=k)for(e=a.a(a.w);d--;)h=e[L(a)<<8|L(a)],c+=h;else{for(c=Array(d),e=0;e<d;e++)c[e]=L(a);for(d=c,c=[],h=e=0;e<d.length;)l=d[e++],128>l?c[h++]=String.fromCharCode(l):191<l&&224>l?(q=d[e++],c[h++]=String.fromCharCode((l&31)<<6|q&63)):(q=d[e++],m=d[e++],c[h++]=String.fromCharCode((l&15)<<12|(q&63)<<6|m&63));c=c.join("")}else for(c=Array(d),e=0;e<d;e++)c[e]=L(a);B(a,b,c)}},function(a){L(a)},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),c=a.a(c),b=a.a(b),B(a,d,b[c])},function(a,b,c){b=L(a),c=L(a),b=a.a(b),B(a,c,f(b))},function(a,b,c,d,e){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=N(a,b),e=N(a,c),c!=a.h&&(d==a.i&&e==a.i?(a.c[c]==k&&B(a,c,""),B(a,c,a.a(c)+a.a(b))):e==a.n&&(0>d?(b=a.a(b),d==a.i&&(b=F(""+b)),c!=a.d&&c!=a.f&&c!=a.o||G(a,c,H(b.length,2)),G(a,c,b)):0<d&&G(a,c,H(a.a(b),d))))},function(a,b,c){b=L(a),c=L(a),B(a,c,function(a){return eval(a)}(a.a(b)))},function(a,b,c){b=L(a),c=L(a),B(a,c,a.a(c)-a.a(b))},function(a,b){b=O(a),B(a,b.O,b.N.apply(b.self,b.C))},function(a,b,c){b=L(a),c=L(a),B(a,c,a.a(c)%a.a(b))},function(a,b,c,d,e){b=L(a),c=a.a(L(a)),d=a.a(L(a)),e=a.a(L(a)),a.a(b).addEventListener(c,R(a,d,e,true),false)},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),a.a(b)[a.a(c)]=a.a(d)},function(){},function(a,b,c){b=L(a),c=L(a),B(a,c,a.a(c)+a.a(b))},function(a,b,c){b=L(a),c=L(a),0!=a.a(b)&&B(a,a.b,a.a(c))},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),a.a(b)==a.a(c)&&B(a,d,a.a(d)+1)},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),a.a(b)>a.a(c)&&B(a,d,a.a(d)+1)},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),B(a,d,a.a(b)<<c)},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),B(a,d,a.a(b)|a.a(c))},function(a,b){b=a.a(L(a)),P(a,b)},function(a,b,c,d){if(b=a.K.pop()){for(c=L(a);0<c;c--)d=L(a),b[d]=a.c[d];a.c=b}else B(a,a.b,a.e.length)},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),B(a,d,(a.a(b)in a.a(c))+0)},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=a.a(L(a)),d=a.a(L(a)),B(a,b,R(a,c,d))},function(a,b,c){b=L(a),c=L(a),B(a,c,a.a(c)*a.a(b))},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),B(a,d,a.a(b)>>c)},function(a,b,c,d){b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),B(a,d,a.a(b)||a.a(c))},function(a,b,c,d,e){b=O(a),c=b.C,d=b.self,e=b.N;switch(c.length){case 0:c=new d[e];break;case 1:c=new d[e](c[0]);break;case 2:c=new d[e](c[0],c[1]);break;case 3:c=new d[e](c[0],c[1],c[2]);break;case 4:c=new d[e](c[0],c[1],c[2],c[3]);break;default:a.g(a.A);return}B(a,b.O,c)},function(a,b,c,d,e,h){if(b=L(a),c=L(a),d=L(a),e=L(a),b=a.a(b),c=a.a(c),d=a.a(d),a=a.a(e),"object"==f(b)){for(h in e=[],b)e.push(h);b=e}for(h=b.length,e=0;e<h;e+=d)c(b.slice(e,e+d),a)}],z.b=0,z.p=1,z.h=2,z.l=3,z.d=4,z.w=5,z.P=6,z.L=8,z.H=9,z.I=10,z.r=11,z.F=12,z.G=13,z.f=14,z.o=15,z.k=16,z.ca=17,z.R=253,z.$=254,z.S=248,z.T=216,z.da=6,z.i=-1,z.n=-2,z.v=-3,z.U=17,z.W=21,z.A=22,z.ea=30,z.Y=31,z.X=33,z.u={},z.D="caller",z.J="toString",z.ga=34,z.fa=36,E.prototype.ia=function(a){return(a=window.performance)&&a.now?function(){return a.now()|0}:function(){return+new Date}}(),E.prototype.Q=function(a,b,c,d,e,h,l,q,m,y,s){if(this.m)return this.m;try{if(this.q=false,b=this.a(this.d).length,c=this.a(this.f).length,d=this.j,this.c[this.L]&&Q(this,this.a(this.L)),e=this.a(this.h),0<e.length&&G(this,this.d,H(e.length,2).concat(e),this.R),h=this.a(this.F)&255,h-=this.a(this.d).length+4,l=this.a(this.f),4<l.length&&(h-=l.length+3),0<h&&G(this,this.d,H(h,2).concat(C(h)),this.S),4<l.length&&G(this,this.d,H(l.length,2).concat(l),this.T),q=[241].concat(this.a(this.d)),window.btoa?(y=window.btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,q)),m=y=y.replace(/\\+/g,"-").replace(/\\//g,"_").replace(/=/g,"")):m=k,m)m=","+m;else for(m="",e=0;e<q.length;e++)s=q[e][this.J](16),1==s.length&&(s="0"+s),m+=s;this.a(this.d).length=b,this.a(this.f).length=c,this.j=d,this.q=true,a=m}catch(v){D(this,v),a=this.m}return a},E.prototype.s=function(a,b,c,d,e,h){try{for(a=this.e.length,b=2001,c=k,d=0;--b&&(d=this.a(this.b))<a;)try{B(this,this.l,d),e=L(this)%this.M.length,(c=this.M[e])?c(this):this.g(this.W,0,e)}catch(l){l!=this.u&&((h=this.a(this.r))?(B(this,h,l),B(this,this.r,0)):this.g(this.A,l))}b||this.g(this.X)}catch(q){try{this.g(this.A,q)}catch(m){D(this,m)}}return this.a(this.k)},E.prototype.ha=function(a,b){return b=this.Q(),a&&a(b),b};try{window.addEventListener("unload",function(){},false)}catch(S){}n("thintinel.th",E),n("thintinel.th.prototype.exec",E.prototype.ha);')})()
```

I spent an hour trying to deobfuscate this, but gave up. I then tried Googling for information about this, via words from the first comment line above, and the URL of the .js file, but nothing too relevant came up.

Then I tried other sites that use ReCaptcha and checked if they were pulling something similar. Finding sites that use ReCaptcha isn't as easy as I thought (I'm sure there are many, it's just not an easy search). The few I found did pull a similarly-named file from the google.com/js/th path, but they tended to have far less code in it than mine.

If this is a legitimate part of ReCaptcha, it seems they could do a much better job of not making it look suspicious. There's no indication of what the hell it is or that it even has anything to do with ReCaptcha.

Right now I'm not too worried, as I'm assuming it IS legitimate. I mainly wanted to get this up someplace for others who may have noticed it and gotten worried. If there are no answers I might just answer it myself with a "yeah it's probably fine".

Comment: The email address is THINTINEL-QUESTIONS@GOOGLE.COM

Comment: Thanks. Even googling THAT didn't return anything useful. I would think if it's legit, that email address or the word "thintinel" would come up somewhere at least...

Comment: @equazcion: And did you try, perhaps, sending an e-mail with your question to that e-mail address, as the comment in the file says?

Comment: @Piskvor: I haven't tried emailing that address. ON the chance this isn't legit, I'd rather not go near it. I might create a temporary email account somewhere and try it, if no one seems to have any info about this...

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ is your friend when trying to deobfuscate :-)

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Tried that. The obfuscators did a very good job here though. Most of the code still remains on one very long line.

Comment: I edited the question and replaced the snippet with the entire code block, in case anyone is interested.

Comment: I use reCaptcha and all assets come from `http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/*`..

Comment: @enapupe: Have you tried using a JS debugger from a browser and checking all the JS files that actually run on your ReCaptcha page? I didn't see this file until I did that.

Comment: I just ran a website which I have ReCaptcha installed with chrome dev tools open in the network tab, there is no script like yours.

Comment: So, I did manage to format the code: http://jsfiddle.net/X4KW9/ ... taking a good  read right now.

Comment: FYI I tried emailing THINTINEL-QUESTIONS@GOOGLE.COM from a temporary email service (guerillamail), but got no reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It creates an object called `thintinel`, in the global scope, and this object is referenced directly by `/recaptcha/api/js/recaptha_ajax.js`.

It's almost certainly legitimate and my best guess is that it checks for a traditional, interactive browser rather than a thin bot-controlled client.

Comment: That seems very true. I did a few steps reverting this script trying to find what it was doing and it makes total sense with that you said.

Comment: Thanks! I had a feeling it was alright. Google could do a much better job of making it look legit. This looks like it may have fallen by the wayside during early development and wasn't given any attention during release. An obfuscated JS page with nothing but a coded email address, that doesn't seem to be documented anywhere... it just looks all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the level of obfuscation this code has, and the fact it is binding something to 'unload' event, I'd say it is not good thing.

Usually legit code justifies itself somehow, this code is a mystery..

The code can be read at http://pastebin.com/AQxkh7E0 (new paste, easier to read)

Edit: I created a post on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/4129/suspicios-obfuscated-javascript-file

Comment: Can bad stuff even come from google.com/js/th/ ? Do they have a public repository of some kind that serves from that path, and that anyone can upload their code to?

Comment: Theoretically nope, but a few weeks ago someone managed to make a phishing of google login page, hosted at google drive, so, the phishing had google ssl verification..

Comment: I'm holding onto hope, as it's hosted at Google, and Google does get pretty crazy about its JS obfuscation from what I've seen previously...

Comment: "Giving the level of obfuscation this code has", so minified js files are by default malicious? Interesting logic you have there.

Comment: @AD7six you really did not took a good look at it.. It is really really obfuscated.

Comment: Thanks for contributing your formatted versions of the code, enapupe. I still couldn't make heads or tails of it, but you did a good job making it manageable. If there was a tool you used (as opposed to regex replaces) I'd love to know which one.

Comment: No tools, I just took it of eval and fixed a few broken lines.. js beautify did the rest.

Comment: @enapupe I think those people used a custom Google Form to do it, though.